# Quartz Cron Trigger with special requirements

Tags: .net, quartz.net, crontrigger

How would you define a Quartz job, with the following requirements:
It must fire every weekday (this is easy), EXCEPT for two specified nth days (like the 15th-16th or the 1st-2nd of every month). I thought about using two triggers, but honestly, I'm not sure how to make the cron expressions the way I need them to be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the cron trigger and adding a [calendar](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/topic1793.html) to the job.

Comment: Hmmm, didn't think of that. Well, I've managed to solve this issue just by making the job check if a specified trigger was executed within a specified interval.